# Is it possible to register someone else's vehicle with SENTRI?

Tags: usa, mexico, sentri

I am looking at applying for [SENTRI](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/sentri) for myself and my family so that we can travel back-and-forth easily between Mexico and the US.

I don't currently own a car, for travel to the US we use a friend's US-registered car.

Is it possible/allowed to register our friend's car into the SENTRI program?

The only thing I've been able to find along these lines is an [old (2005) forum post](http://www.tijuanablog.com/index.php?showtopic=62) which talks about company cars - but in my case the car is privately owned.  The post mentions a notarized letter from the company saying the driver is authorised to use the vehicle, but no source is referenced for this requirement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't yet have a definitive answer, but I have contacted the CBP and it appears they don't have an official policy on this.  The requirements seem to be at the discretion of the specific enrollment center.

Here is their first response:

> You can log into your account and register any vehicle you wish.
>
> If you register your vehicle in SENTRI as part of your initial
>   application, there is no fee for registering your vehicle. If you wish
>   to register another vehicle, you must pay a $42 vehicle registration
>   fee.  There is no longer a requirement to visit an Enrollment Center
>   for a vehicle inspection when registering a new vehicle.
>
> You can register up to 4 vehicles for use in a SENTRI lane, and you
>   can have up 8 SENTRI members registered to a vehicle.  Approved SENTRI
>   members are able to use the Global Entry kiosks when re-entering the
>   U.S. by air and TSA Precheck, as long as they meet the citizenship
>   requirements for Global Entry and their fingerprints and passports are
>   on file.  They are not, however, entitled to any benefits under the
>   NEXUS program through their SENTRI membership.

This seemed to be a bit of a generic answer to me, and although they mention "any vehicle you wish" in the first line, they then go on to talk about "your vehicle" rather than any vehicle, so I asked them to clarify.

Their response to my request for clarification:

> You will need to call the enrollment center and ask the officers for
>   those requirements.
>
> Sometimes individuals have said they were told
>   they could register vehicles with only a letter from an owner and
>   others have stated they were told the owner had to be present when
>   they registered the vehicle.

I will include an update once I hear back from an enrollment center or two.

---

Update:

We have now had our SENTRI interviews.  We received emails from CBP in the days before our interview listing all required documents, one of which was a notarized letter of permission if the vehicle was registered to another party.  We had no issues regarding the vehicle at the interview, and no questions were asked.
The notarized letter was copied and noted in our file, and we were told we must keep it in our car as we may be asked for it when we cross.