# How long does it take to add your car to SENTRI?

Tags: usa, automobiles, sentri

I’m flying to San Diego soon and will be renting a car there. I’d like to do a day trip to Tijuana and using my Global Entry in the SENTRI lanes would make the trip back much faster. How long does it take for new cars to be processed in SENTRI *in practice*? Official wait times are on the order of weeks but maybe it’s much faster in practice?

Comment: A bigger question might be whether you're allowed to add a rental car at all, given that you're not the registered owner of it.  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102271/is-it-possible-to-register-someone-elses-vehicle-with-sentri says that they were able to add a car belonging to a friend, but they needed a notarized letter from the owner, which the rental company almost certainly won't give you.

Comment: @NateEldredge you no longer have to get the car inspected to add it to SENTRI so I’m not sure if that answer is relevant anymore. But good point.

Comment: Just curious, who are you planning to rent a car from (what company)? https://blog.autoslash.com/crossing-the-border-from-the-united-states-to-mexico/

Comment: From what I'm hearing in local facebook pages, people are waiting months for cars to be added to SENTRI.

Comment: And most car rental places in SD will tell you they don't want you taking the car into Mexico.  Better to park at, or take the trolley to, the border, walk across, and then walk or use uber or rent a car in Mexico.

Comment: @Midavalo care to add your answer? I’m also going to ask a separate question shortly about day trip options to Tijuana.

Comment: @CGCampbell Avis. I’m renting as part of a corporate program so I believe I’m allowed to do this.

Comment: @JonathanReez I am reluctant to add an answer as I don't have personal experience myself, and in my 10 mins of searching this morning I could not find the posts I have read on facebook recently so can't even quote them

Comment: @JonathanReez a little searching suggests that the additional insurance Avis requires to enter Mexico and the higher rate charged in San Diego than in Tijuana make it worthwhile for most renters to cross first and then rent.